# How to get the body of an outlook message

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, email, outlook

I have some code that send e-mails.  It creates a default message then allows the user to modify it.  What I would like to do is archive the message that gets sent out but any recipients that may get added.  The problem is when the user clicks send the mail object gets set to null.

```
Public Shared Function SendRFQ(ByVal strRFQID As String, ByVal strTo As String, ByRef EmailSent As Structs.Email) As Boolean

    Dim bRC As Boolean
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    objOutlook = CType(CreateObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
    objEmail = CType(objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)

    With objEmail
        .CC = "Employee@Work.com"
        .Subject = String.Format("RFQ")
        .To = strTo
        .Body = Constants.RFQ.Email.Body
        .Display(True)
    End With

    'objEmail is null
    EmailSent.To = objEmail.To
    EmailSent.Subject = objEmail.Subject
    EmailSent.Body = objEmail.Body

End Function
```

I get an COM exception; "The item has been moved or deleted."

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't call `Display` until after you've populated `EmailSent`.

Comment: Display is what allows the user to customize the message.  If I populate EmailSent first I do not get any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `Send` [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_events.aspx) of the `MailItem`.  The following Console app shows how.  You should be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Module1

    Private WithEvents objEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    Sub Main()

        Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application

        objOutlook = CType(CreateObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
        objEmail = CType(objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)

        With objEmail
            .CC = "a@b.com"
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .To = "jc@d.com"
            .Body = "Body"
            .Display(True)
        End With

        objOutlook = Nothing

    End Sub

    Private Sub objEmail_Send(ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles objEmail.Send
        Console.WriteLine(objEmail.Body)
        Console.WriteLine(objEmail.To)
        Console.WriteLine(objEmail.Subject)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Or you can use the Application.ItemSend event.

Comment: Thanks Jim!  Works perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep the values of the contents of the email and populate your ByRef object:

```
Dim cc = "Employee@Work.com"
Dim subject = String.Format("RFQ")
Dim body = Constants.RFQ.Email.Body
With objEmail
    .CC = cc
    .Subject = subject
    .To = strTo
    .Body = body
    .Display(True)
End With

EmailSent.To = strTo
EmailSent.Subject = subject
EmailSent.Body = body
```

Comment: That doesn't track any changes the user makes.